# Adobe Animate .fla Conversion and publish to HTML 5/JS

Tags: javascript, html, flash, jquery-animate, adobe

Adobe Animate .fla Conversion and publish to HTML 5/JS

The previous person we had doing this task is no longer with the company, and the instructions they left are minimal.  They are probably enough to jog their memory but are not helpful for someone attempting with no Flash/Animate experience.  In our attempts we get a few different results

- The file works correctly in IE but not in any other browser.
- The file opens in IE but cycles through each frame, never stops, and doesn’t load in any other browser.
- The file opens in IE but has no animation, doesn’t respond to clicks, and doesn’t load in other browsers.
- The file doesn’t open anywhere

With our lack of experience with Flash/ Animate, we can’t tell what is the problem. We did try using a file that is unmodified and has a current working HTML5/JS publish, however, when we publish that same file we get the same results as above, while the original works fine.  We believe that it something in the publish of the JavaScript causing the failure.  I attempted to take bad.html and bad.js and overwrite bad.js with the content of good js. This worked, it’s the wrong data, but it worked and is why we believe the publish of the JavaScript is the issue.

The instructions we are following are as follows.

1. Open .fla in Animate
2. Click File --> Convert to --> HTML 5 Canvas (save File)
3. Click File --> Publish Settings

   - Basic tab

     - Uncheck Loop Timeline
     - Check Export images assets (as spritesheet)
     - Uncheck Export Sounds
     - Uncheck Export CreateJS
   - HTML/JS tab (No changes)
   - Image Settings Tab (No changes)
4. Click Publish

I have shared the .fla at https://1drv.ms/u/s!ApKpIVR_uf25hd9MF6pzZPKZjukwQw?e=oEzxRV in the hopes that someone can help and spot the error of our ways.

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: Flash is deprecated and you can have some security issues with it.
https://www.adobe.com/ca/products/flashplayer/end-of-life.html

Comment: The notice about Flash being deprecated [has been around since 2017](https://blog.adobe.com/en/publish/2017/07/25/adobe-flash-update.html#gs.ctytij).

Comment: There are few things you should be aware of. 1) FLA project is published as SWF application, HTML tags and (might or might not) some JS. The fact it doesn't work anywhere but IE probably means that non-IE HTML tags messed up, or your non-IE browsers purged Flash already. 2) Converting ActionScript FLA project into a JavaScript FLA project might not be a matter of a few clicks. If there are scripts, you will probably need to rewrite them all, as JavaScript operates differently and is not directly compatible. Simply put, you will totally need someone who understands Flash + HTML5 + JS thing.